# ruby program to verify the string2 each character is present in the string1

Tags: ruby

I tried Ruby program to verify string2 each character is present in the string1.If it’s present then store the character in a variable and keep on append and print the variable with the final value.

My Code is:

```
string1 = "Print eng formats"
string2 = 'recursive'
for i in 0..string2.length do
  for j in 0..string1.length do
    if string2[i]==string1[j]
      print string2[i]
    end
  end
end
```

but i got an output **"rrerrsie"**. Please help me to resolve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is that output wrong and what should be the correct output? The first 'r' in "recursive" matches both the 'r' in "Print" and the 'r' in "formats", as does the second 'r' in "recursive", so given both your English description and your code, the output can be considered correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not breaking the loop when comparing. The `r` is twice included in the string therefore your code outputs the `r` twice.

Additionally comparing all characters for `string1` with all characters of `string2` is not very performant. The longer the strings the slower this algorithm will be. I suggest using a [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) that doesn't store duplicates and that allows lookup in `O(1)` for a problem like these:

```
string1 = "Print eng formats"
string2 = "recursive"

# create Set for lookup
require "set"
chars = Set.new(string1.chars)

# iterate the second string and output chars that are included
string2.chars.each { |char| print(char) if chars.include?(char) }
#=> rersie
```

Comment: yeah i got it.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dirty: `string2.delete("^#{string1}")`. Deletes everything from string2 which is not in string1.